# How do I create a table from remote JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, web-scraping, html-table

I know how to create a table from JSON. Below is the example code. But I don't know how to connect to remote URLs containing JSON content to be used in the table making function. I found [this](https://api.kwl.cz/examples/json/corsbypass) url to json page and I would like to create the same table with info (continent, country, cases, deaths, recovered and lastupdated). So similar table result as the one in the example. If discussion about this topic exists and has the right results, please write it in a comment but don't delete this topic.

**TABLE.HTML** (JSON is in page, I would like to create table from remote JSON)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Convert JSON Data to HTML Table</title>
    <style>
        th, td, p, input {
            font:14px Verdana;
        }
        table, th, td 
        {
            border: solid 1px #DDD;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            padding: 2px 3px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        th {
            font-weight:bold;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <p id="showData"></p>
</body>

<script>

        var myBooks = [
            {
                "Book ID": "1",
                "Book Name": "Computer Architecture",
                "Category": "Computers",
                "Price": "125.60"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "2",
                "Book Name": "Asp.Net 4 Blue Book",
                "Category": "Programming",
                "Price": "56.00"
            },
            {
                "Book ID": "3",
                "Book Name": "Popular Science",
                "Category": "Science",
                "Price": "210.40"
            }
        ]

        // EXTRACT VALUE FOR HTML HEADER. 
        // ('Book ID', 'Book Name', 'Category' and 'Price')
        var col = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {
            for (var key in myBooks[i]) {
                if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
                    col.push(key);
                }
            }
        }

        // CREATE DYNAMIC TABLE.
        var table = document.createElement("table");

        // CREATE HTML TABLE HEADER ROW USING THE EXTRACTED HEADERS ABOVE.

        var tr = table.insertRow(-1);                   // TABLE ROW.

        for (var i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
            var th = document.createElement("th");      // TABLE HEADER.
            th.innerHTML = col[i];
            tr.appendChild(th);
        }

        // ADD JSON DATA TO THE TABLE AS ROWS.
        for (var i = 0; i < myBooks.length; i++) {

            tr = table.insertRow(-1);

            for (var j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
                var tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
                tabCell.innerHTML = myBooks[i][col[j]];
            }
        }

        // FINALLY ADD THE NEWLY CREATED TABLE WITH JSON DATA TO A CONTAINER.
        var divContainer = document.getElementById("showData");
        divContainer.innerHTML = "";
        divContainer.appendChild(table);

</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data source does not serve data any more. I therefore changed it to a place where statistics compiled by the John Hopkins University (Baltimore, MD) are mirrored on a daily basis. As this data contains *time series*, I had to pre-process them slightly before putting them into the table below. The formatting (=colouring) is then best done by some lines of CSS:

```js
const num=s=>+s.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''),
  cols=["country","cases","deaths","recovered","deathrate"];
fetch('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json').then(r=>r.json()).then(o=>{
  var D=Object.keys(o).sort().map(c=>{
    let dat=Object.values(o[c].slice(-1)[0]);
    dat[0]=c;dat.push((100*dat[2]/dat[1]).toFixed(2)+'%');
    return dat
  })
  document.querySelector('table').innerHTML='<tr>'+
  cols.map(s=>
    `<th>${s}</th>`).join('')+'</tr><tr>'
     +D.map(r=>`<td>${r.join('</td><td>')}</td>`)
       .join('</tr><tr>')+'</tr>';
 })
```

```css
th:first-child {text-align:left}
th:nth-child(n+2), td:nth-child(n+2) {text-align:right}
th:nth-child(2) {background-color: #00aa22}
th:nth-child(3) {background-color: #ffff00}
th:nth-child(4) {background-color: #ff0000}
th:nth-child(5) {background-color: #ff9900}
td:nth-child(2) {background-color: #55ee77}
td:nth-child(3) {background-color: #ffff55}
td:nth-child(4) {background-color: #ff0000}
td:nth-child(5) {background-color: #ffb84d}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Purely out of interest I added some sort functionality to the table. Click on any of the column headers to sort according to that column (click again for reverse order):

```js
const num=s=>+s.replace(/[^0-9]/g,''),
  cols=["country","cases","deaths","recovered","deathrate"];
const tblsort=ev=>{const e=ev.target; if (e.tagName=='TH'){
   const i=[...e.parentNode.children].indexOf(e); srtdir[i]=srtdir[i]>0?-1:1;
   [...tbd.children].sort(i>0?srtnum(i):srttxt(i)).forEach(tr=>tbd.appendChild(tr));
  }
};
const srtdir=[];
const srtnum=i=>(a,b)=>srtdir[i]*num(a.children[i].textContent)-num(b.children[i].textContent);
const srttxt=i=>(a,b)=>srtdir[i]*a.children[i].textContent.localeCompare(b.children[i].textContent);
fetch('https://pomber.github.io/covid19/timeseries.json').then(r=>r.json()).then(o=>{
  var D=Object.keys(o).sort().map(c=>{
    let dat=Object.values(o[c].slice(-1)[0]);
    dat[0]=c;dat.push((100*dat[2]/dat[1]).toFixed(2)+'%');
    return dat
  })
  document.querySelector('table').innerHTML='<thead><tr>'+
  cols.map(s=>
    `<th>${s}</th>`).join('')+'</tr></thead><tbody><tr>'
     +D.map(r=>`<td>${r.join('</td><td>')}</td>`)
       .join('</tr><tr>')+'</tr></tbody>';
  tbd=document.querySelector('tbody');
  thd=document.querySelector('thead').addEventListener('click',tblsort);
 })
```

```css
th {cursor:pointer}
th:first-child {text-align:left}
th:nth-child(n+2), td:nth-child(n+2) {text-align:right}
th:nth-child(2) {background-color: #00aa22}
th:nth-child(3) {background-color: #ffff00}
th:nth-child(4) {background-color: #ff0000}
th:nth-child(5) {background-color: #ff9900}
td:nth-child(2) {background-color: #55ee77}
td:nth-child(3) {background-color: #ffff55}
td:nth-child(4) {background-color: #ff0000}
td:nth-child(5) {background-color: #ffb84d}
```

```html
<table></table>
```

Comment: Thank´s it´s very helpful.

Comment: And I would  like to ask how to recolor titles background of cases:yellow, deaths:red, recovered:green and deathrate:orange. And all values of cases to light yellow, all values of deaths light red, all values of recovered:light green and all values of deathrate:light orange... Of course I can workd with bgcolor of tr, td but If I recolor some tr, the entire content is colored. not just what I need. That can you ask me how to do this? Thank´s

Comment: This is  desired colors, first color will be color of title, second color will be color of all values:                                                                                                             _green:00aa22, 55ee77 /
yellow: ffff00, ffff55 /
red: ff0000, ff0000 /
orange: ff9900, ffb84d_

Comment: Thank you again :-)

Answer (score 0):

You would first use either [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) to attempt grabbing the remote data, then converted it via [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse). If successful the object can be used to generate your table like you would in your sample code.

If you don't feel comfortable using 'vanilla' JS, you can find plenty of libraries for both XMLHttpRequest and Fetch.